# Create elasticksearch N number indecies each with N number documents

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

I'm trying to create the 365 indices with 2000 documents for each index. And also I would be nice to set to `index => "test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"` - for each day with new data per day. Actually, I need to simulate the creation of indexes per day where each index has about 2000 records. I'm using elasticsearch 6.2.

```
export const initTest = async types => {
    try {
        let client = createClient()

        const templateSettings = {
            index_patterns : ['*'],
            settings: indexTemplateSettings,
            mappings : types.reduce((p, type) => ({
                ...p,
                [type] : {
                    'numeric_detection': true,
                    _source : {enabled : true},
                },
            }), {}),
        }

        await client.indices.putTemplate({
            name: 'default',
            body: templateSettings,
        },(error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of index template completed', response)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
}

export const pushTest = (message, type, index) => new Promise(async resolve => {
    try {
        let client = createClient()

        await initTest(['Call'])

        await client.index({
            index: `${YYYY.MM.dd}`, //per day new data
            type,
            body: message,
        },
        (error, response) => {
            logger.silly('Pushing of data completed', response)

            resolve(response)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(e)
    }
})


for (let index = 0; index < 365; index++) {

    let messageTest

    for (let documents = 0; documents < 2000; documents++) {

        messageTest = {

            location: `Room_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            zone: `Zone_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            personName: 'person name',
            personRoom: `Room_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}`,
            pageSize: 10,
            cancelPerson: 'person name',
        }
    }

    pushTest(messageTest, 'Call', index)
}
```

Comment: Could you specify a question or describe an issue you have.

Comment: Each day when I create index I need to add to index the date when this index was created